# SQL in php script stopped working after upgrading php version on the server

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

My php webpage stop showing the results from database.
After HDD failure new system was installed on new HDD, with upgraded .php version on ubuntu (before it was version 5.xx now its version 7.xx).
I am not .php guru so I dont know how to properly debug .php code from command line on the ubuntu server.

I hope you guys can tell me is everything ok with syntax since .php upgrade.
Or how can I actually see result/error after statement execution?

```html
<?php // Ĺ ÄÄŚÄ†Ĺ˝ĹˇÄ‘ÄŤÄ‡Ĺľ
require_once("config.inc.php");
require_once("databasess.inc.php");

DBSS_Open(DATABASE_SS_HOST, DATABASE_SS_USERNAME, DATABASE_SS_PASSWORD, DATABASE_SS_NAME);

$data = array();

foreach ($GLOBALS["VM_operators"] AS $VM_operator => $VM_operator_options)
 {
 # Number of available channel
 $query = "SELECT gpools_view.* FROM gpools_view, gsm_pools WHERE gpools_view.pool_id=gsm_pools.id AND gsm_pools.name = '".$VM_operator_options["gsmpool"]."';";
 $result = DBSS_Query($query);
 $data["rtco_".$VM_operator."_availablechannels"] = DBSS_NumRows($result);
 DBSS_FreeResult($result);
 # Number of channel
 $query = "SELECT gpools_view.* FROM gpools_view, gsm_pools WHERE gpools_view.pool_id=gsm_pools.id AND gsm_pools.name = '".$VM_operator_options["gsmpool"]."' AND (gpools_view.status = 40 OR gpools_view.status = 30);";
 $result = DBSS_Query($query);
 $num_channels = DBSS_NumRows($result);
 DBSS_FreeResult($result);
 $data["rtco_".$VM_operator."_channels"] = $num_channels;
 if ($num_channels < ($data["rtco_".$VM_operator."_availablechannels"]/2))
  {
  $data["msg_rtco_".$VM_operator."_channels"] = "Low channels for <b>".$VM_operator_options["name"]."</b>!";
  }
 else
  {
  $data["msg_rtco_".$VM_operator."_channels"] = "";
  }
 # Number of calls
 $query = "SELECT gpools_view.* FROM gpools_view, gsm_pools WHERE gpools_view.pool_id=gsm_pools.id AND gsm_pools.name = '".$VM_operator_options["gsmpool"]."' AND gpools_view.status = 40;";
 $result = DBSS_Query($query);
 $num_calls = DBSS_NumRows($result);
 DBSS_FreeResult($result);
 $data["rtco_".$VM_operator."_calls"] = $num_calls;
 # Percentage
 if ($num_channels > 0)
  {
  $percentage = round($num_calls/$num_channels*100);
  $data["rtco_".$VM_operator."_percentage"] = $percentage." %";
  if ($percentage >= 90)
   {
   $data["msg_rtco_".$VM_operator."_percentage"] = "Overload on <b>".$VM_operator_options["name"]."</b>!";
   }
  else
   {
   $data["msg_rtco_".$VM_operator."_percentage"] = "";
   }
  }
 else
  {
  $data["rtco_".$VM_operator."_percentage"] = "0 %";
  }
 }

echo(json_encode($data));

?>
```

Best regards.

Comment: you have created a wrapper for a PHP mysql library (I am guessing it's mysql_*) but you haven't posted the wrapper code. So we are left guessing. But the guess is an easy one because mysql_* was discontinued in php 7

Comment: Can I somehow downgrade php 7 to php 5 on the machine to preserve the old functionality?

Comment: yes. [search engine of your choice] has enough answers for that topic. however, the better way would be to *upgrade your code* so you don't use functions that have been *deprecated* in PHP5 for a while now - that way, your code will even be future-proof.

Comment: I don't know how to re-code existing php scripts to new version of php. I need to preserve the old scripts and I need to make them work again (somehow). I installed version 5.6 of php, since I could see that old apache2 server was using mod php5, so I enable that mod also, but it still doesn't work... damn I am missing something....

Comment: upgrade your code instead, if you were using mysql_ now use mysqli_

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Missing component was pgsql, and in php script pgconnect() returned and error.

Installing the pg component solved the issue.
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql

Guys thank you very much for help!